# Importing contents of jar file not working

Tags: java

Sorry for the very nooby and simple question but this has been driving me mad all day:

I am trying to create a simple program that will help me sort some jpg files into folders. I want to use metadata-extractor to extract the date the photos were taken (https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/).

My problem is whenever I try to compile, it says the packages do not exist. I have the jar file in the same directory as my test java file, along with the picture I'm trying to test on.

I set up the classpath in the Git Bash as follows:

```
javac -cp "metadata-extractor-2.6.4.jar:." PictureSort.java
```

along with the (few simple) lines of code:

```
import java.io.File;
import com.drew.metadata.Metadata;

class PictureSort
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         File file = new File("IMG_1244.JPG");
         Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(file);
    }
}
```

I have examined the contents of the Jar file for what I need and Metadata.java is contained in com/drew/metadata/Metadata so thats why I used said import statment on the second line.

But... 
I am getting the following errors:

```
PictureSort.java:2: error: package com.drew.metadata does not exist
PictureSort.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
     Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(file);
            ^
 symbol:   class Metadata
 location: class PictureSort
 PictureSort.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
     Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(file);
                                ^
 symbol:   variable ImageMetadataReader
 location: class PictureSort
 3 errors
```

I have tried looking for an answer but I can't seem to find a solution that will work for me. Can anyone point me in the right direction for what I'm doing wrong? I don't have much experience in the side of utilising jars. Help is really appreciated.

Comment: The import should likely be `import com.drew.metadata.Metadata`. A jar name ending in _-src.jar_ suggests this is not a binary containing class files; merely a source code archive. You will need to obtain the binary library.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, I have downloaded the binary library. It has only com/drew/* so I have changed that in the code and classpath so it isn't source anymore. But the problem still persists, same error with package "com.drew.metadata" not existing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's `source.com.drew.metadata`. Cause package name always starts with a lowercase letter. Also I don't think package name is like that. Try `com.drew.metadata`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick check of the [Javadoc for Metadata](http://javadoc.metadata-extractor.googlecode.com/git/2.7.0/com/drew/metadata/package-summary.html) and you'll see at the top that `Metadata` is in package `com.drew.metadata`

That said, you appear to have a *source* jar, not the compiled classes:

> javac -cp "metadata-extractor-2.6.4-src.jar:." PictureSort.java

You need to download the `.jar` containing the compiled classes. It appears you can do so from here: https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/downloads/detail?name=metadata-extractor-2.6.4.zip

Download the `.zip`, unzip it, get the `.jar`

Once you've done that, your import will be:

```
import com.drew.metadata.Metadata;
```

And you'll compile via:

```
javac -cp "metadata-extractor-2.6.4.jar:." PictureSort.java
```

Comment: I have following these steps exactly for the problem still presists.. very confused here.